# Get Remote site url by SOQL APEX in salesforce

Tags: remote-site-settings

I want to get value of remote site url in salesforce
(Ex: I want to get http://abc.com like image below).
How can I use query SOQL in APEX to get it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ToolingAPI to access the RemoteSiteSettings. In developer you can try to query like below.

```
select id, SiteName, EndpointUrl from RemoteProxy
```

In the above query EndpointUrl is field which you are looking for.

You need to check the "Use Tooling API" check box to true else you will not get result.